# Are there a limited number of Oculi?

Tags: child-of-light

The game lets you take Oculi you already have and craft new/better ones. Yesterday after getting my first red/blue/green I immediately crafted a while one. This of course diminishes the total number of Oculi I have available to equip. I then worried that perhaps I had wasted some precious resource.

So the heart of the question:

Is there any harm in crafting Oculi willy nilly or should I covet them and wait to craft?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oculi drop randomly after battles, and can be found in chests. Enemies are respawned after you quit and re-enter the game, so you can farm them that way.

Comment: I'm a little confused at what you're saying "yes" to, as the asker's last sentence was an "or" statement and the title asks if there *is* a limited number, but your answer implies there is not. Can you clarify?

Comment: @FAE watcha talkin bout? :з

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get them as drops from random encounters, so I think you're good to craft away. I'm still pretty early into the game so downvote away if I'm wrong on that :)